# How to use variable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, variables, session, select

Now is the time to show no mercy for this question but i think this may be the best way to me to learn.
I want to do a for each in one small script i have been working after work.
I want to monitor if any sessions are idle and if are superior to 50 minutes, i want to logoff.
So i use this

(quser)

PS C:\Windows\system32> (quser) 
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME

> John                rdp-tcp#1           9  Active          .  21-11-2018 22:15
>    Ryan                  rdp-tcp#0          11  Active       5:07  21-11-2018 10:59

If i use this scrip, i can capture the IDLE Time and compare, this is working fine

```
**$separator = "," # you can put many separator like this "; : ,"
 $partas = (quser) -replace '\s{2,}', ','
$parts = $partas.split($separator)
$data = $parts[10]
if ($data -eq "." )
{ $data = "0"
}
$datanow = [int]$data 
$toto2 = [int]"45"
if ([int]$datanow  -gt [int]$toto2 ){
logoff $parts[6] 
Write-Output "Terminator Mode GOD "}
else 
{
( Write-Output "Not my president!"
)
}**
```

As you can see, i splite the parts and select the one i want

```
**$separator = "," # you can put many separator like this "; : ,"
 $partas = (quser) -replace '\s{2,}', ','
$parts = $partas.split($separator)
$data = $parts[10]**
```

But is one session is local, the $parts[x] does not match the real camps and the script stop working.

So i need to make a simpler code, to select the IDLE TIME and the ID to logoff if condition is match.
Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance!c

Comment: Would you consider using WIM/CIM instead of quser.exe?
If so, looking over this existing script might help:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LoggedOnUser-Gathers-7cbe93ea If that doesn't help you, take a look at this blog post attempting to solve a similar opportunity.
https://sysadminasaservice.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/quser-and-powershell/

Comment: you can use the script linked after this to get the output of that exe into a PoSh object. then use those properties to do your select. ///// [PowerShell] function Get-QUserInfo - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/pe9rkP60

Comment: @Lee_Dailey gotta work on your markdown: `[text](uri)`

Comment: Thans a lot, I will give a try and return the output after a try.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - i don't like hiding the URL, so as long as it aint _required_, i won't use address hiding. [*grin*]